# I cannot boot windows 10 after installing ubuntu 17.04. Windows now stuck at advanced startt up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 17.04, boot-repair

I am actually quite stressed out as if I lose my data it will have dire consequences for me. So I installed Ubuntu 17.04 yesterday and chose the "install alongside windows" option. Everything installed properly and Ubuntu works perfectly. Although I do have window entries in my GRUB upon boot when I click on them my Windows gets stuck at automatic repairs.  Ive tried countless of fixes and nothing work. Here is a summary of my system as provided by Boot -repair.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4pWmMNqQxt/

Please could anyone assist me as I am severely panicking.

Kind regards
David

Comment: First, please edit your title to specify the correct version of Ubuntu you installed.  Your message says `17.04`, the pastebin link shows `17.10`.  Version `17.04` isn't supported.  Second, your description shows a properly functioning Ubuntu, which passes the boot over to Windows.  Your problem is with Windows and the repair of what is going wrong with Windows loading after it has control.  It's a Windows issue and would require Windows support.  You can boot to Windows with Grub, but Grub or Linux can't repair Windows.  Check http://superuser.com or **a Windows specific forum** for support.